# how to detect the new database when change database in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The problem that when i change the new database then application not detected the new database and retreive error

> The model backing the 'DBContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

but i don't using Migrations so i don't update-database by Package Manager Console
How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does detect changes in your database. The database differs from the model. The error message.

This error is thrown when the hash stored in the migrations history table does not match a calculated hash. (Have a look at __MigrationHistory table, might be under system tables)

If you delete this table the check is essentially disabled. You can achieve something similar by adding `Database.SetInitializer<YourContextType>(null)` to the startup of your application. The latter disables database creation from within that application, so if you want to create the database by code, you would need to do this from a separate application (for example an console app). I prefer to go this way for web applications.

Secondly: if you change your database manually (change columns, add tables, etc.) you need to adjust your model. So for each DDL statement, change your code.

If you are not using code first, you could update your existing model in the designer.

Comment: @TienKenji Then please accept the answer for others searching for the same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when I first started with code first and mvc. the answer below is absolutely correct but you should go to the ASP.net website and do some tutorials on code first migrations. you need a better understanding how update database and initialize and migrations work.